# PHP global $lang = array

Tags: php, global

So what I am trying to do is set up (so I don't have to do it later) global languages at first we will only have English but plans are to have japanese an others. I theer for in my index.php have inlcuded the language file like so

```
global $lang;
require_once("system/languages/en.php");
```

in the system/languages/en.php I have the following

```
$lang = array();
$lang["sitename"] = "SiteName";
$lang["welcomeheader"][0] = "The Network for home Owners";
$lang["welcomeheader"][1] = "free";
$lang["welcomeheader"][2] = "to join";
```

however when i put the following on a .tpl file

```
<?=$lang["welcomeheader"][0];?>
```

I get the following error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: lang in /home/devipe/public_html/template/main/welcome.tpl on line 16
```

I am wondering how do I get a global to register even if in another PHP page.

Comment: That should work already, as long as none of the codes above were inside a function, if so then you need to refer to the global variable there as well.

Comment: Please never ever use globals - it leads to incredibly messy code and will become very difficult to maintain. Think about encapsulating your translations in a class

Comment: can you show en.php? like hanky says if it's in global scope already it should show. now if it's smarty that's another thing. you have have to assign it to the template.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky well our .tpl files are call inside function would that count?

Comment: Yes it would, then inside the function you need to again type `global $lang;`

Comment: can i put it inside the class are as i want to to work no matter the function @Hanky웃Panky

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Comment: Please use an existing system build for this purpose, like gettext. I18n is not a wheel which needs to be reinvented yet again. You don't even realize yet what trouble you'll get into later with this system.

Answer (score 0):

STEP1: system/languages/en.php should be

```
<?php

  return array(
     "sitename" => "SiteName",
     "welcomeheader" =>array("The Network for home Owners","free","to join")
  );

?>
```

STEP2: Declare $lang variable

```
<?php
 $lang = require_once("system/languages/en.php");
?>
```

STEP3: And your .tpl file should be

```
<?php global $lang; ?>
<?=$lang["welcomeheader"][0];?>
```